# how to fix Komodo PHP dll missing error?

Tags: php, xampp, komodo, komodoedit

When I open *.php files my Komodo gives me this error

[image]

I checked and those dll do exist, they are not missing! I recently did a clean up of the temp folders for Windows, and this error start coming up.

and this is what the Komodo Error log shows :

[image]

I tried re-installing still I'm getting same problem!

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Find the `.dll` extension from the official source and install?

Comment: @DarylGill Thanks so so much! I only downloaded copied the PHP folder,and I had stop the servers for a while, but now it totally works fine! Why don't you make this an answer so I can choose your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Find the .dll extension from the official source and install?

Comment: Thanks @Paul . and Daryl Gill already suggested that, it was the Kommodo, I changed the interpreter redirection from XAMPP to the PHP installed